# How does UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl works?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I dont get it, I have this code:

```
return JavaScript(string.Format(
   "window.location = '{0}'",
   UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl("Index", this.HttpContext)));
```

The code is inside two pretty generic "Create" methods that works with POST. Each of the two methods are in different controller classes.

Now for method **A** that is called with the URL `http://localhost:56688/Businessrule/Create`, when the code is executed I get redirected to `http://localhost:56688/Index`.

But for method **B** called from `http://localhost:56688/FormulaField/Create` I get redirected to `http://localhost:56688/FormulaField/Index`.

... really I don't get it, and the microsoft documentation isn't helping out much http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.generatecontenturl.aspx (now, IMHO, that's a pretty crappy documentation for a method)

Comment: It's open source, take a look yourself. http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/e7526daecf9d#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fPathHelpers.cs

Comment: I'll take a look, but in my opinion is sad to hear "Open source = lack/poor documentation" ... I expected a little more from Microsoft...

Comment: You asked "How does it work?" You can't really answer that any better then the source code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as pointed by **asawyer** how it works is answered by the code itself:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/UrlHelper.cs

It turns out that if the string that you pass begin with "~" the method will call PathHelpers.GenerateClientUrl, but if the string doesn't begin with "~" it will just return the same string unchanged.

But still I don't undertand why I'm getting different results. Anyway seems that I'll have to look closer to the raw response passed to the browser...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your missing the controller name. apperently, you're being redirected to the Index action in the same controller.

It's what the MVC Route engine do, if he does not find the controller name, he assign a default value, in this case, the controller from witch the action has been executed.

Try something like :

```
UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(@"~\ControllerName\Index", this.HttpContext)
```

Comment: Sure, if I add the Controller part of the URL it will work. But the point is: why is it working different in the same scenario? (one "Index" URL with the controller part, the other without it...)

Comment: I think that your explanantion isn't exactly accurated, if you look at the source code as **asawyer** suggest you will find what exactly the code does. In my answer I give a hint (and the link to the source code)... Anyway, if you want to "solve" the problem, your solution works